# How to index and deindex NSUserActivities from Spotlight

Tags: swift, indexing, nsuserdefaults, corespotlight

I am trying to wrap my head around `NSUserActivity`s and I am not entirely sure on how to use them properly. I have setup my NSUserActivity properly like so:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeItem as String)
attributeSet.title = "Title"
attributeSet.contentDescription = "Description"    

let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: ActivityType.activity.rawValue)
activity.persistentIdentifier = ActivityIdentifier.activity.rawValue
activity.title = "Title"
activity.requiredUserInfoKeys = ["Key"]
activity.userInfo = ["Key": data]
activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
activity.contentAttributeSet = attributeSet

self.userActivity = activity
self.userActivity!.becomeCurrent()
```

Now the activity gets indexed via the `becomeCurrent()` method. When I click on the activity in Spotlight everything works fine and the activity can be restored using the `userInfo` property.

But how do I delete the activity from Spotlight once it has be used (restored)? In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647405/how-to-delete-a-specific-nsuseractivity-search-index) the user recommends to use either `deleteAllSavedUserActivities(completionHandler:)` which works but I can't use since I don't want to delete all activities or `deleteSavedUserActivities(withPersistentIdentifiers:completionHandler:)` which does not work. For the [first method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/2980672-deleteallsaveduseractivities) the documentation says following however to the [second method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/2980673-deletesaveduseractivities) this does not apply:

> Deletes all user activities stored by Core Spotlight...

Instead I could index the activities with the Core Spotlight API like so:

```
let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: ActivityIdentifier.activity.rawValue, domainIdentifier: "DomainID", attributeSet: attributeSet)
CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([item]) { error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        print("successfully indexed item")
    }
}
```

and delete them with the `deleteSearchableItems(withIdentifiers:completionHandler:)` method. The problem with that is, I have to set the `relatedUniqueIdentifier` of my `attributeSet` and then the `userInfo` will be empty once I try to restore the activity ([regarding post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776758/core-spotlight-userinfo-is-always-empty)).

So what should I do, should I use both Core Spotlight and NSUserActivity and use `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` to save the data instead of using the `userInfo` (why would apple to that?, why would they add the userInfo then?) or should I index my activity without Core Spotlight, but how do I delete the activity from Spotlight in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is just one thing I figured out: In the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchableitemattributeset/1649285-domainidentifier) for the `domainIdentifier` property of the `CSSearchableAttributeSet` it sounds like you are supposed to use this property to delete the `NSUserActivity`

> Specify a domain identifier to group items together and to make it
>   easy to delete groups of items from the index. For example, to delete
>   a user activity, you can set this property on the contentAttributeSet
>   property of the NSUserActivity object and then call
>   deleteSearchableItems(withDomainIdentifiers:completionHandler:) on the
>   default().